# error using browserify with babelify "'import' and 'export' may apper only with 'sourceType: module'"

Tags: ecmascript-6, gulp, babeljs, browserify, babelify

I'm getting `Error: Parsing file app.js: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (1:0)`

while using gulp with browserify and babelify

I only get the issue with one specific import [vue-masked-input](https://github.com/niksmr/vue-masked-input)

my gulp task looks like this

```
gulp.task('js', () => {

    let b = browserify({
        entries:   './resources/assets/js/app.js',
        debug:     true,
        transform: [
            babelify.configure({
                presets: [["es2015"]]
            }),
            'vueify'
        ]
    });

    return b.bundle().on('error', function (e) {
        console.log(e.toString());
        this.emit('end');
    })
            .pipe(source('app.js'))
            .pipe(buffer())
            .pipe(prod ? uglify() : util.noop())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'))
        ;
});
```

I tried a few suggestions I found around the web
including:

- `presets:    [["es2015", {modules: false}]],`
- `sourceType: 'module',` (under babelify.configure)